# Converting TXT to CSV with a complex custom delimiter

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-365

I am trying to convert following text file into `csv` by using [Text Import Wizard of Data Excel 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857). File seems to have come from a source that is using `1252: Western European (Windows)` encoding.

By looking at the content of the file, I decided to use `^|^,^|^` as a custom delimiter that seems to work except the the first and the last columns still have `^|^` in their values (as shown in image below).

**Question**: What should be a better way of using a custom delimiter in the following file so we don't get `^|^` value in the first and last column?

**Remarks**: The actual file is a huge (1GB) file with about 150 columns. The below is just a sample used for the brevity of this post.

**Snapshot of the txt file**:

```
^|^Col0^|^,^|^Col1^|^,^|^Col2^|^,^|^Col3^|^,^|^Col4^|^,^|^Col5^|^,^|^Col6^|^,^|^Col7^|^
^|^1234^|^,^|^4600869848^|^,^|^6000.00^|^,^|^2021-12-20 10:16:19.3600000^|^,^|^False^|^,^|^^|^,^|^^|^,^|^2^|^
^|^5431^|^,^|^3425143451^|^,^|^30000.00^|^,^|^2021-12-13 10:27:44.9030000^|^,^|^False^|^,^|^^|^,^|^^|^,^|^2^|^
..............
................
```

**Excel Text Import Wizard result**:
[image]

Comment: It looks like `^|^` is actually serving as the `text qualifier` rather than the `delimiter`, i.e. like quotation marks around the entirety of each field's data. This is why there is only one at the beginning and end of your data. Your data's actual delimiter is the comma. Your best bet is to pre-process the text by deleting `^|^` outright and using the comma as the delimiter. Alternatively, (especially if your data includes commas) search and replace `^|^` with `"` or `'` and set the text qualifer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you've made the decision to add to the text file the string ^|^,^|^ the results are consistent with the request to the software.
The start and end of your text lines are not ^|^,^|^ but are ^|^ which provides the results as displayed.

Consider to replace in your text file the string containing the comma with the string ^|^ which will still provide the delimiting you require.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply remove `^|^`, you have a right CSV

```
<input.csv sed -r 's/\^\|\^//g' >output.csv
```

```
+------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+------+------+------+
| Col0 | Col1       | Col2     | Col3                        | Col4  | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 |
+------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+------+------+------+
| 1234 | 4600869848 | 6000.00  | 2021-12-20 10:16:19.3600000 | False | -    | -    | 2    |
| 5431 | 3425143451 | 30000.00 | 2021-12-13 10:27:44.9030000 | False | -    | -    | 2    |
+------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+------+------+------+
```

If you have some `,` in fields content, you can convert your file to Tab Separated Values:

```
<input.csv sed -r 's/^\^\|\^//g;s/\^\|\^$//g;s/\^\|\^,\^\|\^/\t/g' >output.tsv
```

```
Col0    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7
1234    4600869848      6000.00 2021-12-20 10:16:19.3600000     False                   2
5431    3425143451      30000.00        2021-12-13 10:27:44.9030000     False                   2
```

I'm using `sed` utility. It's always in Linux system, but you can install and use it also on win.

Comment: I have used that sample input. I will edit this answer thank you @Mockman

Comment: Also, if you replace the `^|^` with `"` in your first solution, then the result will be a csv that handles `,` in the content.